# Is it possible to automatically set the default_payment_method while CheckoutSession Stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying figure out how to set default payment method to Stripe customer.
Is it possible to automatically set the default_payment_method while CheckoutSession Stripe?

Currently, I use code below for CheckoutForm

```
import { addDoc, doc, onSnapshot, collection, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { auth, firestore, functions } from "../../firebase";
import { getStripe } from "./initializeStripe";

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid) {

  const stripePK = await getStripe();
  
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "customers", `${uid}`, "checkout_sessions"), {
    price: "price_12431",
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  })

  // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
  onSnapshot(doc(firestore, "customers", `${uid}`, "checkout_sessions", docRef.id), (doc) => {
    const { sessionId } = doc.data();
    if(sessionId) stripePK.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: sessionId});
  });
}
```

And I attach photo of customer field that I want to change
[image: Photo]

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do or what isn't doing what you expect? When using Checkout to create a subscription, the payment method should automatically be set as the `default_payment_method` for that subscription.

Comment: Yup, I attached all code and pics to post, for some reason Checkout Session doesn't save __default_payment_method__